# Overlapping Elements Style in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native

I want to create Overlapping Elements using React Native.

An example can be Trixie App as follows -

[image]

I want to create a box like that in-between blue & white color.

Can it be done using Flexbox or do we need Absolute Positioning ? Bcz if I create using Absolute positioning, lets assume I give it `height:100` (the blue color) then the `white` chat box might not be halfway up & down on various devices depending on their screen dimensions.

Also how to make it so that its responsive on various devices like Tablets, etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

It can be done using `position: absolute; top: -25;` & it has to use `position: relative` in the inside.

I'll post a link to complete repo soon enough. Answering only this much for now. Repo will be provied in 2 days.

Also, a repo has been made to do it much simpler - https://github.com/entria/react-native-view-overflow