# How can I achieve overlapping views like the ones circled in this attached photo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried using position absolute but it won't work, click to see picture
[Overlapping image views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLYrP.jpg) Also you can see my code below.

```
<View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <View style={{ height: 20, width: 20, borderRadius: 30, backgroundColor: 'grey', justifyContent: 'center', borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'white' }}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.image }}
              style={{ height: 20, width: 20, borderRadius: 10 }}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{ height: 20, width: 20, borderRadius: 30, backgroundColor: 'grey', justifyContent: 'center', borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'white' }}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.image }}
              style={{ height: 20, width: 20, borderRadius: 10 }}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{ height: 20, width: 20, borderRadius: 30, backgroundColor: 'grey', justifyContent: 'center', borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'white' }}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: item.image }}
              style={{ height: 20, width: 20, borderRadius: 10 }}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
```

[result of using negative margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVBHI.png)

Comment: How about negative left margins for the 2nd and 3rd images?

Comment: Please post a code snippet of what you're working with.

Comment: @stever I have tried the negative margin and it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlapping Elements Style in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639742/overlapping-elements-style-in-react-native)

Comment: Can you include a picture of what IS rendered?

Comment: @stever see above (the result of using a negative margin to see what I got) when I  surround the images with a view. I would like for it to be the reverse with the image to the left on top

Comment: Both pictures look the same to me.  Sorry.

Comment: @stever that was my mistake, you can check now

Comment: Still, the "result of using negative margin" picture looks the same as the circled item in the top pic.

Comment: Oh I see the difference..  You want the furthest left image on top? If so have you tried using` z-index: -2` on the far left and z-index: -1 on the middle one?

Comment: @stever it works with positive zIndex, thanks a bunch!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Cool I posted the result as an answer.  If it is correct would you accept it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use negative left margins for the 2nd and 3rd images, and to set the `z-index` attributes in the layering order desired.